# how to protect bash scripts from being read

Tags: script

Good evening guys. As the title suggests I was wondering if it is possible to protect bash scripts that also contain sensitive data from being read and tampered with by other users using the system.

Let me explain: the scripts are run in an office on a Debian computer. My user "jack" is a sudoers user, and it uses the "sudo" command without input a root password (necessary for my work).

My problem is that other users logging in via sudoers user without input a root password in ssh and could read or manipulate the scripts damaging my work.
I realized that only fixing the permissions is useless.

What could be the best solution to my problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologize if my request seemed a little stupid. I know that root can have full control over everything. So suppose I don't just want others to read the script code.
The computer is shared for work reasons with other colleagues. The scripts I use are for personal and non-business purposes.
So the solution would be to encrypt the scripts?

Comment: I was wrong, others use the PC via non root but sudoers user without input to the root password, they can then read the data by typing `sudo cat script1`

Comment: "Damaging your work" could mean several things.  "Bob deletes or rewrites important parts of your carefully-written work" can be fixed with a version control system.  "Later processes are dependent on the original version of the script" requires that that Bob be educated as to the later needs, or his manager being brought into the conversation.  "Bob changes the script to do The Bad Thing, runs the altered script, and changes it back to make you look guilty" means that someone at work is undermining you, and technical fixes can only fix that a little.

Comment: I wrote my earlier comment before I saw your comment about the script being personal.  @Jax2171 , if you have scripts for personal and non-business purposes, why are you running them on a computer you don't own?

Comment: The question is as legitimate as my purpose :), I do not have a high speed internet connection and having the possibility of being able to use a remote non-paying PC I like the idea of being able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Any root user will be able to access files within the local filesystem. No exceptions.

Your options are:

1. Encryption.

   - Decrypt it and execute it with a strictly manually entered password.
   - Storing the password locally to automate things will put you right back where you are now.
2. External file system.

   - NFS mounts can [squash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#Root_squash) root privileges, preventing a remote root from accessing a local file. You could then automate by copying the script out of the root-inaccessible area as your non-squashed user account, execute it locally as root and immediately delete it. A sudoer can `sudo su jack` to gain access to it by masquerading as your user.
   - Retrieve it from a password protected and otherwise inaccessible ssh server and execute it locally.
3. Obfuscation.

   - Store it somewhere that looks like it's just another system/config file and name it something ordinary.
   - Anyone who actively looks can find it.
4. Discussion.

   - Why do so many people think they need root access on a shared devise?
   - Why are you running personal stuff on a shared work machine?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to protect a script from being tampered with by *root*. Even with LSMs like SELinux, ultimately the whole idea of "root" is that it's the highest-privileged account on the system, and as such root access should only be given to trusted people.

The only option is to put the script on another system entirely and have users call it over the network (e.g. via restricted SSH shell or via some HTTP-based API). Root on one server doesn't mean root on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that hasn't been addressed by the previous answers is to create restrictions in your sudoers file.  Instead of allowing any number of users to access a direct root shell, create scripts that address certain tasks your users need to accomplish, and allow each user to only run those scripts which that user requires.  This would presumably prevent users from inspecting or tampering with scripts they aren't authorized to access.

You might also want to look into a tool called [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) which is designed to securely delegate tasks which require root privileges, without giving away full root shell access.

Answer (score 1):

Try `shc` to encrypt the shell script and convert it to a binary.

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/

Comment: I tested shc by encrypting the scripts, although many think it is a palliative, but once I run the script in the background with `nohup` I can't verify if the process is actually running. Using the `pgrep script_encrypted.x` command does not detect the pid  It seems that on `top` are seen as generic bash processes. A big problem for me.